# Calculate product of a column, grouped by id name in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

The following SQL script,

```
Select * From
(Select To_Char(A.Pricdate, 'dd-mm-yyyy') As  Pricedate,  A.apples, A.name
, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY A.name ORDER BY A.pricedate asc) AS rank 
From Table1 A
Where 1=1
And A.Pricedate>=To_Date('01-01-2021', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
And A.Pricedate<=To_Date('30-06-2021', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
And Not A.apples<0 
) B
Where 1=1
And B.Rank=1
```

, which should yield the following output:

```
fromdate    pricedate   name    apples  
    26-03-2021  24-03-2021  Heidi   4   
    26-03-2021  25-03-2021  Heidi   5   
    26-03-2021  26-03-2021  Heidi   3   
    26-03-2021  27-03-2021  Heidi   1   
    26-03-2021  28-03-2021  Heidi   7   
    26-03-2021  29-03-2021  Heidi   6   
    26-03-2021  30-03-2021  Heidi   7   
    28-03-2021  27-03-2021  Elsa    5   
    28-03-2021  28-03-2021  Elsa    1   
    28-03-2021  29-03-2021  Elsa    1   
    28-03-2021  30-03-2021  Elsa    2   
    24-03-2021  22-03-2021  Carl    1   
    24-03-2021  23-03-2021  Carl    1   
    24-03-2021  24-03-2021  Carl    2   
    24-03-2021  25-03-2021  Carl    5   
    24-03-2021  26-03-2021  Carl    5   
    24-03-2021  27-03-2021  Carl    3   
    24-03-2021  28-03-2021  Carl    2   
    24-03-2021  29-03-2021  Carl    1   
    24-03-2021  30-03-2021  Carl    2
```

What I now wish to create is a column, `Total`, that for each `name` contains the product of the apples consumed for the period that begins from the `fromdate`, specific to each name, and ends on the `30-03-2021`

```
    fromdate    pricedate   name    apples  Total
    26-03-2021  24-03-2021  Heidi   4       882
    26-03-2021  25-03-2021  Heidi   5       882
    26-03-2021  26-03-2021  Heidi   3       882
    26-03-2021  27-03-2021  Heidi   1       882
    26-03-2021  28-03-2021  Heidi   7       882
    26-03-2021  29-03-2021  Heidi   6       882
    26-03-2021  30-03-2021  Heidi   7       882
    28-03-2021  27-03-2021  Elsa    5       2
    28-03-2021  28-03-2021  Elsa    1       2
    28-03-2021  29-03-2021  Elsa    1       2
    28-03-2021  30-03-2021  Elsa    2       2
    24-03-2021  22-03-2021  Carl    1       600
    24-03-2021  23-03-2021  Carl    1       600
    24-03-2021  24-03-2021  Carl    2       600
    24-03-2021  25-03-2021  Carl    5       600
    24-03-2021  26-03-2021  Carl    5       600
    24-03-2021  27-03-2021  Carl    3       600
    24-03-2021  28-03-2021  Carl    2       600
    24-03-2021  29-03-2021  Carl    1       600
    24-03-2021  30-03-2021  Carl    2       600
, where e.g. `Total` for Heidi is 882=3*1*7*6*7 SINCE fromdate begins on the 26-03-2021.
```

To calculate the product I am contemplating using a formula similar to `Cast(Exp(Sum(Ln(Cast(A.apples As Number))) Over (Partition By a.name)) As Total`, but I am not sure how to create a column for which the values to include in the product are dependent on the date specified in column `fromdate` and vary across `names`.

Thank you in advance. Sorry for the weak explanation. I tried to do my best, but found it difficult to express my intention.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ln()` and `exp()` to emulate a `product()` aggregation function:

```
Select b.*,
       exp(sum(ln(apples) over (partition by name)) as apples_product
From . . .
```

Note:  The result is not an integer.  You might want to `round()` if you want an integer result.

EDIT:

You can use conditional logic in the `sum()`:

```
Select b.*,
       exp(sum(case when pricedate >= fromdate then ln(apples) end ) over (partition by name)) as apples_product
From . . .
```

Comment: Hi Gordon. Thank you for your input. However, my question mainly concerns how I can calculate a product for which the values to include depends on the date in column `fromdate` and not so much how I calculate the product. Maybe I do not entirely understand your answer.